# Test automation tools avaiable for BlackBerry and iPhone

Tags: iphone, blackberry, automation, testing

What test automation tools are available for BlackBerry and iPhone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pickings are slim, but here's a few ideas.  [TestQuest](http://www.testquest.com/) specialise in automation on mobile.  If you could get a VNC client on either you could try [Eggplant](http://www.testplant.com/) or [VNC Robot](http://www.t-plan.com/robot/).  You could also check the [mobile section](http://www.sqaforums.com/postlist.php?Cat=0&Board=UBB29) on SQAforums for further discussion on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

[DeviceAnywhere](http://www.deviceanywhere.com) Test Automation is available for all major mobile platforms (including BlackBerry and iPhone).

Answer (score 1):

For iphone automation try fonemonkey

Answer (score 0):

**BlackBerry**

- [BlackBerry smartphone simulator](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Automation-and-Performance-testing-on-Black-Berry-Simulator/td-p/460375)

**iPhone**

- [UIAutomation](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html)
- [Google Toolbox for Mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/wiki/iPhoneUnitTesting)
- [UISpec](http://code.google.com/p/uispec/)
- [Bromine](http://code.google.com/p/bromine/)